# Windows 7, Detecting hard drives; Done; No drives found?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, bios, sata

I recently reinstalled windows 7 on a Gigabyte GA-X58A-UD3R (revision 2.0) motherboard with an SSD hard drive.  I was reading about IDE vs AHCI and the consensus seemed to be that AHCI was better unless you needed to support a legacy OS.

So in the BIOS I switched the SATA channel mode from IDE to AHCI.  Now since doing that windows gives a message:

`"Detecting hard drives; Done; No drives found"`

This is then followed by a "PCI Device Listing" and a "Verifying DMI Data Pool" message.

Then windows precedes to boot up normally (the only odd thing after starting is that the hard drive is showing in the `Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media` system tray item).

On the previous Windows installation, the BIOS had been set to IDE and I did not see this message.  Why is it showing this message and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

By enabling SATA mode to AHCI, you enable the onboard SATA controller. Any harddrives connected through SATA (small plugs) will have to be set into a RAID configuration. In order for this to happen, you have to configure the harddrives through the RAID controller's own BIOS. This `"Detecting hard rives; No drives found"` is the message done by the RAID controller BIOS initialization, and is completely normal.

If you go into the SATA bios and setup a raid controller, it will find the drives there. Note that doing this will wipe the data on the disk. So if you made a complete backup and you are going to reinstall windows a next time, that might be a time to switch to a RAID configuration. The reason to do that is because it is faster.

Comment: But I am not interested in a RAID configuration I just want to use AHCI

Comment: You asked why you suddenly see the "Detecting hard drives; No drives found" message, and I explained it.